# Tool to document web API

Tags: java, api, documentation-generator

**Context**
I have a soap web API which is built in java with spring.

The API is part of a service which is one component from a microservice.

There is no possibility of manually writing the documentation. It has to be generated by a tool.

Is there a tool that:

- can be integrated to my project
- Will scan the code of my service (mainly the endpoints of the service)
- is free
- has a reasonable large community
- won't require me to write any docstrings, the tool should inspect my code and generate the documentation based on the code, not on the docstrings

The generated documentation should:

- be in `pdf/html` format
- cover each endpoint in the service (the list of required parameters, url to endpoint), basically I want that information about
  each endpoint to be included in the generated `pdf/html`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend either doxygen or javadoc. Javadoc is probably easier to setup, and may already be integrated with your IDE.

Comment: Isn't there something that will generate the docs based on the code, not on the docstrings?

Comment: @cristid9 doxygen and javadoc make use of the code but also need some information for the human reader as they cannot guess wat everything does mean.